# Javascript timer wrong in math game

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am doing a simple math game in javascript. Everything works  until the moment when the timer needs to be reset on starting generating new question. On this moment something very strange happens. The timer start showing some strange negative or unreal positive values.

To experience my problem first press the play button then start playing the game. Enter only true answers. After some tries you will see that something with the timer is wrong.

**Full code below:**

https://jsfiddle.net/6xq847gf/

https://codepen.io/Atatanas/pen/KyyLgK

```
function timer(timeleft){
    timeleft = 5;
    timeTime = setInterval(function() {
        timeleft--;
        document.getElementById("countdown").textContent = timeleft;
        if(timeleft <= 0){
            clearInterval(timeTime);
        }
    },1000)
}
function clearTime() {
    clearInterval(timeTime);
    timeleft=5;
    timer(5);
}
```

Comment: In your function `timer()` replace `timeleft--;` by `--timeleft;`

Answer (score 2):

You generated multiple instances of setInterval(). That is why when you did clearInterval(), only immediate setInterval instance is cleared. But, the other instances are still running.

1. I commented those lines which have to be removed.
2. You have to call clearInterval() before another setInterval(). So, I put clearTime() before load().

```js
var number1, number2, max = 10,
            sign, numberSigns = 2,
            output, userOutput,points=0,timeleft = 10,timeTime;
   
function endGame(){
hide('points');
hide('countdown');
hide('base');
randomColor();
}
function timer(timeleft){
  timeleft=5;
  timeTime = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdown").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(timeTime);
    }
 
 
 },1000)
 }
 function clearTime(){
 clearInterval(timeTime);
 timeleft=5;
 //timer(5);
 }
        function check() {
            userOutput = document.getElementById('enterNumber') .value;
            if (userOutput) {
   if(userOutput==output){
               document.getElementById('points').innerHTML=points=points+1;
      clearTime();
               load();
      randomColor();
   
            }else{
   
   alert('WRONG');
        }
  }else{
  alert('Please enter something.');
  }}

        function load() {
            number1 = Math.round(Math.random() * max);
            number2 = Math.round(Math.random() * max);
            sign = Math.round(Math.random() * numberSigns);
            if (sign == 1) {
                if (number1 < number2) {
                    load();
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('outputMath').innerHTML = number1 + "-" + number2;
                    output = number1 - number2;
     timer(5);
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById('outputMath').innerHTML = number1 + "+" + number2;
                output = number1 + number2;
    timer(5);
            }
        }

        function hideStart() {
            document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
            randomColor();
            load();
            show('base');
   show('points');
   show('countdown');
        }

        function hide(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            randomColor();
        }

        function show(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        }

        function randomColor() {
            var bgcolorlist = new Array("#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50");
            document.body.style.background = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgcolorlist.length)];
        }
```

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            transition: 1s;
            outline: none
        }
        ::selection {
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
        }
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(229deg, #a1c4fd, #c2e9fb, #cfd9df, #667eea, #764ba2, #e2d1c3, #89f7fe, #66a6ff, #48c6ef, #6f86d6, #feada6, #a3bded, #6991c7, #13547a, #80d0c7, #93a5cf, #434343, #000000, #93a5cf, #ff758c, #868f96, #596164, #c79081, #dfa579, #09203f, #96deda, #50c9c3, #29323c, #485563, #1e3c72, #2a5298, #b7f8db, #50a7c2, #2193b0, #6dd5ed);
            background-size: 7400% 7400%;
            animation: backgroundGardient 500s ease infinite;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes backgroundGardient {
            0% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
            50% {
                background-position: 100% 18%
            }
            100% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes backgroundGardient {
            0% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
            50% {
                background-position: 100% 18%
            }
            100% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
        }
        @-o-keyframes backgroundGardient {
            0% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
            50% {
                background-position: 100% 18%
            }
            100% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
        }
        @keyframes backgroundGardient {
            0% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
            50% {
                background-position: 100% 18%
            }
            100% {
                background-position: 0% 83%
            }
        }
        h1#frontText {
            position: fixed;
            top: 10vh;
            font-size: calc(1vh + 1vw + 3em);
            color: white;
            width: 70vw;
            left: 15vw;
        }
        div#menu {
            border-radius: 10em;
            opacity: 0.8;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: #ecf0f1;
            color: black;
            width: 80vw;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle:
        }
        button#startGame {
            font-size: calc(1vh + 1vw + 3em + 10vmax);
            background-color: #141414;
            color: white;
            border: none;
        }
        @keyframes pulse_animation {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
            30% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
            40% {
                transform: scale(1.08);
            }
            50% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
            60% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
            70% {
                transform: scale(1.05);
            }
            80% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
            100% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
        }
        button#startGame:hover {
            background-color: #ecf0f1;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow: hidden;
            outline: none;
            transform: rotate(360deg);
            color: black;
            border-radius: 1em;
            transition: 2s;
            box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
            animation-name: pulse_animation;
            animation-duration: 5000ms;
            transform-origin: 70% 70%;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
        }
        div#menu:hover {
            width: 100vw;
            border-radius: 0;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: 2s;
            box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
            background-color: #141414;
        }
        div#base {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: #ecf0f1;
            border: calc(1vh + 1vw) solid #ecf0f1;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
   opacity:0.8;
     box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
        }
        div#base:hover {
            border-radius: 0.1em;
   opacity:1;
     box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
        }
        p#outputMath {
            font-size: calc(2vh + 2vw + 5vmax + 5em);
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        input#enterNumber {
            width: 50vw;
            font-size: calc(1vh + 1vw + 1em + 1vmax);
            border: 2px solid black;
   text-align:center;
        }
        input#enterNumber:hover {
            border: 2px solid orange;
        }
        input#enterNumber:focus {
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
        button#submit {
            min-width: 45vw;
            min-height: 10vh;
            background-color: #141414;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 2em;
            font-size: calc(1vh + 1vw + 1em + 1vmax);
            color: white;
        }
        button#submit:hover {
            min-width: 50vw;
            background-color: #2c3e50;
            border-radius: 0.2em;
            color: white;
        }
div#points{
background-color:#e74c3c;
color:white;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
position:fixed;
top:0vh;
right:0vw;
border:1vw solid #e74c3c;
font-size:calc(1vh + 1vw + 2em);
display:none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
 div#countdown{
 background-color:#3498db;
color:white;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
position:fixed;
top:0vh;
left:0vw;
border:1vw solid #3498db;
font-size:calc(1vh + 1vw + 2em);
display:none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
 }
div#result{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='menu'>
        <button onclick='hideStart()' id='startGame'>►</h1>
    </div>
    <div id='base'>
        <p id='outputMath'></p>
        <input id='enterNumber' type='number'> </input>
        </br>
        </br>
        <button onClick='check()' id='submit'>Check</button>
    </div>
   <div id='points'>0</div>
   <div  id="countdown"></div>
   <div id='result'></div>
</body>

</html>
```